# How to make the drawableLeft of a Android Button keep rotating?

Tags: android, button, rotation

I need to create a button where there is a icon in the left and a text in the right. After pressing the button, I want to see there is an animation of rotating image at the place of the left icon in the button.

### I know how to rotate a image with ImageView, but it is not helpful to my current requirement.

I tried to use AnimationDrawable, but it did not work either, there is no animation but only the first png file shown. It is then same whatever I use the background or leftDrawable of the button to run the AnimationDrawable. The code is as below:

```
package com.example.layout;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimationDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class TestLinearlayoutActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Button locationTitleButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.LocationTitleButton);
        //locationTitleButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.loading);

        locationTitleButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.loading, 0, 0, 0);

        Drawable[] locationTitleButtonDrawables = locationTitleButton.getCompoundDrawables();
        AnimationDrawable animDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) locationTitleButtonDrawables[0];
        //AnimationDrawable animDrawable = (AnimationDrawable) locationTitleButton.getBackground();
        animDrawable.start();
    }
}

//loading.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:oneshot="false">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loc1" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loc2" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loc3" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/loc4" android:duration="200" />

</animation-list>

// layout file, main.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:padding="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:gravity="fill_horizontal" android:layout_margin="0dp">

    <Button android:id="@+id/LocationTitleButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ellipsize="end" 
        android:scrollHorizontally="true" 
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Add location" 
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button android:textColor="#FF000000" 
        android:layout_weight="0" 
        android:id="@+id/AddLocationButton" 
        android:text="Search" 
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginLeft="-8dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using an [`AnimationDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#Frame).

Comment: Using AnimationDrawable I need to have several bitmap to simulate the animation. I have only 1 bitmap, I used to use Animation as the following to rotate the picture <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rotate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromDegrees="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
    android:toDegrees="+360" />   Any solution for rotating a single bitmap?

Comment: Sorry, any solution for rotating a single bitmap in the drawableLeft of a button?

Comment: @George_BJ: Not that I know of, since you do not have an `ImageView` to work with. Since you may want to disable the button anyway (unless clicking it multiple times in succession has meaning), I'd recommend you have an `ImageView` adjacent to the `Button`.

Comment: I still met problem when using AnimationDrawable with a Button, I just edit my question to involve the code.

Comment: @George_BJ: Then what you want is probably not automatically supported.

Comment: The animation is ok if I start it inside a onClick of a button instead of at onStart. Maybe the drawable is not ready for animation ;). However, then I met a new problem, if I initially set a bitmap to drawableLeft, then change(setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds again) to another bitmap or AnimationDrawble, it will be crash of stack overflow. I did not find any API to release the original drawLeft in google doc. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: @George_BJ: Beats me. I recommend opening a fresh question on that one.

Comment: That's not helpful. Some code and explanation would have been helpful. You have always been great at solving problems @CommonsWare. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

I have also face this issue and I have tried all above solution but no one have worked for me. I have found solution [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html#start%28%29). Android document says that don't call start() in the onCreate(Bundle) method of activity call it in onWindowFocusChanged(boolean) function. So I do it like this :

```
@Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus){
    if(hasFocus){
        final AnimationDrawable d=(AnimationDrawable) mBtnView.getCompoundDrawables()[0];
        d.start();
    }
}
```